# Creating an Infopath form that sends an email 

Tags: c#, email, outlook, infopath

I am trying to include the text written by enduser in a textfield in an InfopathForm (textfield,multiline,paragraphbreaks and scroll bar if necessary) in an email to the relevant Department.

I always get this error "The name 'remarkmain' does not exist in the current context"

these are some parts of the code i used to define and include in mail:

```
string remarkmain = xnMyForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:field104", ns).Value;

string BodyAcc = "New Internal Employee " + Titlee + " " + fullname + ".\n Employee is     joining " + Comp + " as of " + HireDate + ".\n\n Please view the general information below:\n " + bodyHD + "\n" + bodyED + "\n" + bodyDOB + "\n" + bodytitle + "\n" + bodylast + "\n" + bodyname + "\n" + bodyLang + "\n" + bodyComp + "\n" + bodydep + "\n" + bodyPos + "\n" + Bankacc + "\n" + add + "\n" + CostCtreVZW + "\n" + CostCtreCVBA + "\n\nWork Schedule\n" + WorkMon + "\n" + WorkTue + "\n" + WorkWed + "\n" + WorkThurs + "\n" + WorkFri + "\n" + WorkFDSch + "\n\n" + ContractN + "\n" + EmpN + "\n" + MGR + "\n" + Teamlead +"\n\n" **+ remarkmain** + "\n\n";
```

I am new to c# and this form i m creating in Infopath ( 2007 )

Comment: are these two lines of code in same method?

Comment: thanks man... I bow my head in shame

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered submitting certain values to a form library and using sharepoint workflows via sharepoint designer to send the mail? The sharepoint workflow variable selection and general interface is generally expansive and pleasant and the functionality is extensive.

Comment: yes sharepoint was my first option but since i m working with a very deadly deadline i have been told to just work it out in infopath :s

Answer (score 0):

See to that `strign BodyAcc="New Internal Employee+....remarkmain+....;` is in `remarkmain` scope

Use StringBuilder if you have too many string concatinations

```
StringBuilder BodyAcc = new StringBuilder
BodyAcc.Append(New Internal Employee);
BodyAcc.Append("\n");
BodyAcc.Append(remarkmain);
```